# Select ID's where average rating between

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I have 2 tables:

table "biz" and table "biz_rating"

**biz**

- biz_id (int)
- name (varchar)

**biz_rating**

- biz_rating_id (int)
- biz_id (int)
- rating (int)

I want a query to select ALL biz rows where the average rating is between 1-2, or 3-4, or < 5 or > 5 (rating is a number from 0 to 5).

I have literally NO IDEA how to start.

I  have something like this now:

```
SELECT
    biz_id
FROM
    biz
WHERE
    biz_id IN
    (SELECT biz_id FROM biz_rating WHERE AVG(rating) BETWEEN 0 AND 5)
ORDER BY
    biz_id ASC
```

but that's not working at all.

Comment: Add GROUP BY and switch from WHERE to HAVING in the sub-select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the table if you want the name along with id

```
 select biz_id,name,b2.avgrating
 from BIZ as B1,
( select biz_id as bid, avg(rating) as avgrating
 from biz_rating
 group by biz_id 
 having avg(rating) between 0 and 5) as B2

 where B1.biz_id=B2.bid
```

This will also select the average rating if you want

Answer (score 0):

Just use aggregation.  You don't even need a `join` for this:

```
select br.biz_id
from biz_rating br
group by br.biz_id
having avg(rating) between 1 and 2;  -- or whatever limits you want
```